# Conjugacy class trivial proof

Tags: group-theory

Disclaimer: I am still new to the subject of *conjugacy classes*, *class equations* and *centralizers*. Some guidance to solving this problem would be greatly appreciated on my part. I would like to know how to approach the following question:

> Show that a finite group has exactly one conjugacy class *if and only if* it is trivial.

**Thoughts**

To some, the proof may be trivial (no pun intended), but to me, it's not. I want to understand what is going on here. I would imagine that if the question were to say "Show that a finite group has exactly $2$ conjugacy classes *if anf only if* it has order $2$", then we would apply a similar argument. So, if this were the case, then we would see some sort of pattern, but in order to move beyond, I need to understand *how to approach* my initial problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a finite group with exactly one conjugacy class.
This means that $1$ must be inside the conjugacy class.
Let $x\in G$. Then $x$ must be conjugate to $1$.
Hence $x=g1g^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$.
Thus $x=1$.
We conclude that $G=1$.

Comment: Aren't we suppose to show  that $G$ is abelian?

Comment: We need to show that $G$ is trivial, that is $G=\{1\}$ where $1$ is the identity of $G$. @CartesianBread

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry I didn't see your comment as I was typing it up. I will delete it.

Comment: Since this is an *if and only if* statement, I would have to show the statement is true $\Leftarrow$ correct?

Comment: @CartesianBread Yes but the converse is easy. If $G=1$, the conjugacy class of $G$ is 1 since $1$ is conjugate to itself.

Comment: Alan Wang: That's what I had. Just wanted to make sure that's all.